# Both DC's able to connect to branch office, Branch DC can only connect to one local DC

Tags: firewall, freebsd, pfsense, cisco-vpn

I am stumped on this one, I appreciate any help with this scenario because 
this just seems odd.

We have 3 domain controllers:
DC1 - 192.168.1.2 - main office (LAN port of PFSense)
DC2 - 192.168.1.4 - main office (LAn port of PFSense)
PFSense - 192.168.1.1 Static IP on LAN port. Used as gateway for DC1 and DC2 and 
the rest of the LAN.
Gateway (RV082) - 192.168.3.1
|
Branch Office Gateway (RV082) - 192.168.0.1
DC3 - 192.168.0.101 - branch office connected via Gateway-Gateway VPN (Cisco 
RV082)

**Both DC1 and DC2 are able to ping an connect to DC3.
DC3 is currently able to ping and connect to DC1 but unable to ping or connect 
to DC2.**

The below tracert shows the paths taken from DC3. I can't figure out what that 
172.*.*.* addresses are any why DC1 works but DC2 does not. Also can't figure 
out why connecting to both DC's takes a different path at hop #4.

**Tracert from 192.168.0.101 (DC3)**

Tracert 192.168.1.2 (DC1)
Tracing route to 192.168.1.2 over a maximum of 30 hops
1 <1 ms <1 ms <1 ms 192.168.0.2
2 6 ms 6 ms 6 ms 64-89-6-100.static.wntpr.net [64.89.6.100]
3 7 ms 18 ms 19 ms ras-180-5.wntpr.net [196.12.180.5]
4 12 ms 12 ms 12 ms 172.30.252.97
5 12 ms 12 ms 12 ms 192.168.1.2
Trace complete.

Tracert 192.168.1.4 (DC2)
Tracing route to 192.168.1.4 over a maximum of 30 hops
1 <1 ms <1 ms <1 ms 192.168.0.2
2 6 ms 6 ms 6 ms 64-89-6-100.static.wntpr.net [64.89.6.100]
3 6 ms 7 ms 7 ms ras-180-5.wntpr.net [196.12.180.5]
4 11 ms 11 ms 11 ms 172.30.253.125
5 172.30.253.125 reports: Destination host unreachable.
Trace complete.

Is there a PFSense configuration issue? Because we have been able to connect 
without any issues in the past.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're missing a route, or have incorrect policy routing on your LAN rules forcing that traffic to the Internet, the traffic is going over the Internet rather than the VPN.

Comment: The traffic that is going over the internet appears to successfully reach DC1 however.  At this time, we do not have any rules set within PFSense besides allowing all LAN and WAN traffic through.

Comment: Thank you so much for your information.  I actually was able to find out that our ISP router (located in our server room) seems to be the issue.  They are working on it now.  Our configuration seems to be okay.

Answer (score 0):

Network unreachable usually means that the reporting system doesn't know how to get to the relevant network.

Host unreachable usually means that the reporting system can reach the network but not the host in question.

In your case, a host unreachable message may be a problem with a firewall service rule, NAT rule/table, a routing misconfiguration, or the ARP cache on the device reporting the message. My guess is that the 172.30.x.x addresses are the VPN endpoints on each side of the VPN connection. Find the endpoint that's using 172.30.253.125 and look at it's service rule set, NAT rule set, routing configuration, and dynamic and/or static ARP table.

Comment: Thank you so much for your information.  I actually was able to find out that our ISP router (located in our server room) seems to be the issue.  They are working on it now.  Our configuration seems to be okay.